# Don't show the Next or Done buttons in the Android VKB

Tags: codenameone

How can I prevent the showing of the Next or Done buttons of the Android VKB in a Codename One app?

Currently, for my app, they are a mess: the next button of the VKB doesn't focus the next field, but the previous. After tons of trials, I didn't find a way to make them working correctly *(but there are fine on iOS and on the Simulator)*. I also tried to override the Layout.overridesTabIndices(com.codename1.ui.Container) and Layout.getChildrenInTraversalOrder(com.codename1.ui.Container) methods in the Form, but nothing changed on Android.

I supposed two possible causes: the use of a Form inside a Form or, more probably, the fact that I replace all the TextFields and Pickers in the same Form (and other components). Maybe the fact that the inner Form is deeply changed results in a confusion for the Android mapping of the "next" button.

That's why my request: because I didn't find a way to make the "next" button useful, I'm asking how I can avoid that it's been shown.

Thank you

Comment: Good news! Finally I found a test case for my issues with the "next" button of the VKB: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting forms would probably mess with the focus traversal/tab order.

Normally you should be able to override `public TabIterator getTabIterator(Component start)` to return a blank iterator. I'd suggest doing the same for both the parent and child form to disable the "next" feature.

Comment: I've just completed a test: removing the outer Form from my app doesn't solve this issue, so it's not a problem of nested Forms.